# Parsing from json it only selects the last element?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing

Today someone tried to steal my login info via a phishing site. So i decided to spam that site with random emails and passwords, i found a piece of code and it seems to work.
Code:

```
import requests
import os
import random
import string
import json
while True:
        try:
                chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*()'
                random.seed = (os.urandom(1024))

                url = 'http://domain/index.php'

                names = json.loads(open('names.json').read())

                for name in names:
                        name_extra = ''.join(random.choice(string.digits))


                username = name.lower() + name_extra + '@yahoo.com'
                password = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(8))

                requests.post(url, allow_redirects=False, data={
                'email': username,
                'pass': password
                })
                print ('sending password %s and password %s' % (username, password))
        except Exception as error:
                print(error)
```

names.json

```
[
"Liam",
"Noah",
"Alaric",
"Decker",
"Eliezer",
"Ramiro",
"Yisroel",
"Howard"
]
```

My issue is that, everytime i run the program it will only pick the last name from the json list.
So it will send "Howard1" "Howard2" "Howard3" and so on. It will ignore every other name from the list and pick the last one..

Comment: HINT: Where does `name` in `name.lower()` come from?

Comment: Hmm, isn't that to have lowercase names?

Comment: You missed my point. Yes, `name.lower()` makes the content of `name` lowercase. But I'm asking you to think about where the variable `name` is actually defined. HINT: it's the looping variable of your `for` loop. You use it *after* the for loop, so what do you think the value would be?

Answer (score 0):

You obviously loop through the `names` list and assign each time `name_extra` new. The last value it keeps is the last name of the list. So you should indent the next following 4 statements like this:

```
for name in names:
    name_extra = ''.join(random.choice(string.digits))
    username = name.lower() + name_extra + '@yahoo.com'
    password = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(8))

    requests.post(url, allow_redirects=False, data={
        'email': username,
        'pass': password
    })
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, i tried to indent the 4 statements, it not giving me any errors but its not working :( It's just blank